# How to setup / process multiple message types in Broker Services

Tags: sql-server-2008, service-broker

I'm just starting to figure out broker services but I have a question with regards to multiple message types / queues, etc...  The situation is quite simple;

I have a job queue (time based), and as each job is 'processed', the results are stored into a table.  A trigger will sit on the results table and use broker services to process each result (asynchronously).  Each result (XML) can be different based on the type of job so I need a stored proc for each type.  I'm guessing I need multiple message types to accomplish this, but...

1. Would I also need multiple queues, one for each message type?
2. Would I need multiple contracts as well?
3. Would I need multiple services?
4. Know of any good design patterns for something like this?

Ideally, I would like one queue with many readers (1 per type) but I'm not certain this is possible given that I can only have 1 stored proc per queue.  When I create multiple message types and multiple queues, it seems that I will also need multiple services as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with (using Remus' answer about sticking with a single contract/queue/service).

Create specific message/contract/queue/service names based upon the type:

```
create message [//MyPrefix/SomeTypeMessage]
create queue dbo.SomeTypeQueue
create service [//MyPrefix/SomeTypeService]
create contract [//MyPrefix/SomeTypeContract]
```

So, 'SomeType' is the type that can be found in the inserted data somewhere.  When the trigger is created that calls begin conversation, the type is used to concat the different sysnames.  Based upon what data is found in 'myTypeDataField', the record will be shipped to different queues/procs.

```
declare @handle uniqueidentifier, 
        @service sysname, 
        @contract sysname,
        @messageType sysname,
        @myType varchar(50)


set @myType = (select myTypeDataField from inserted)
set @messageBody = (select * from inserted for xml auto)

set @service = N'//MyPrefix/' + @myType + 'Service'
set @contract = N'//MyPrefix/' + @myType + 'Contract'
set @messageType = N'//MyPrefix/' + @myType + 'Message'

begin tran

    begin dialog conversation @handle
    from service @service
    to service @service, 'current database'
    on contract @contract
    with encryption = off;

    send on conversation @handle
    message type @messageType(@messageBody);

commit
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to stick to one service/queue/contract. Multiple message types are ok. You should code your async processing activated proc something like this (pseudocode):

```
begin transaction;
receive message into @msg
switch @msg.message_type
case 'A': exec proc_for_a @msg;
case 'B': exec proc_for_b @msg;
...
case 'Z': exec proc_for_z @msg;
end
commit;
```

If you ever done old-style [windows programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#designing_proc) with WM_PAINT/WM_CREATE etc the activated procedure can be very similar, with the SSB message type playing the role of the WM_XXX. This is because event drivent programming is similar to event driven programming...

Comment: Thanks Remus.  I'm going to stick with the one service/queue/contract, but I found a better way to broker the data to the different queues.  Check out my answer.